# How to use grep to find in a directory by a regex?

Tags: regex, bash, find

I tried

```
grep -R '.*invalidTemplateName.*' -regex './online_admin/.*/UTF-8/.*'
```

to find all occurences of possible mathces of the '.*invalidTemplateName.*' regex within a directory regex pattern `'./online_admin/.*/UTF-8/.*'`, but it doesn't work. I got the message:

```
grep: ./online_admin/.*/UTF-8/.*: No such file or directory
```

If I use

```
grep -R '.*invalidTemplateName.*' .
```

it looks up in all subdirectory of the current directory that's overwhelming. How can I specify a directory pattern in grep? Is it possible?

Comment: Does your `grep` support the `-regex` option?

Comment: why do you have to use ``grep``, isn't ``find`` the better choice?

Comment: Use your shell to match the paths to search for: `grep -R 'invalidTemplateName' ./online_admin/*/UTF-8/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find might be a better choice here:

```
find ./online_admin/*/UTF-8/* -type f -exec grep -H "invalidTemplateName" {} \;
```

Find will locate all files in the locations you want, including subdirs of `UTF-8` and then execute `grep` on each file. the `-H` argument ensures the filename will be printed along with the match. If you want only the filename, use the `-L` switch instead.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me., Couldn't you explain what `{} \;` means at the end of the line?

Comment: `{}` represents the filenames located by `find`. The `;`  represents the end of the `-exec` argument, but needs to be escaped with the backslash so it's not interpreted by the shell

Answer (score 1):

with `find` you could do something like that:

```
find /abs/path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -name '.*invalidTemplateName.*'
```

using the `name` argument you can directly filter by names. you can also use wildcards for the filter-string. 
using the `maxdepth` argument you can specify the level of recursion to look up the files. 1 means to look up in `/abs/path/to/directory`, 2 means to look up in `/abs/path/to/directory` and in the first level of directories in `/abs/path/to/directory` as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: question is about finding files that contain pattern, not finding files the name of which contains pattern.